# How to get the current time in UTC?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to get the current time in UTC in a UWP application. This should be a simple matter of constructing a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.datetime) object

```cpp
DateTime const now{ clock::now() };
```

and accessing its [UniversalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.datetime.universaltime) field. However, that field does not appear to have been projected into C++/WinRT.

How do I get the current time in UTC using C++/WinRT?

Comment: For reference, the documentation linked to from this question has since been updated: *"In C++/WinRT, this field does not exist, because in that language projection `DateTime` is a specialization of [std::chrono::time_point](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/standard-library/time-point-class)."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a documentation bug. That field doesn't exist in C++/WinRT. Instead, `DateTime` is projected as a [std::chrono::time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). But similar to C++/CX, the documentation for the struct (not the field) is still somewhat accurat - it has the same granularity as [FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724284). But even easier than extracting the value youself, `winrt::clock` provides static methods `to_file_time` and `to_time_t` that convert `DateTime` to
FILETIME or [time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t), respectively.

I'll get the documentation fixed up, and I've been meaning to write a blog post about how C++/WinRT seamlessly interops with std::chrono for timekeeping. I'm a a fan of std::chrono, and incorporating it into C++/WinRT was my idea, so the haters know who to blame. :)

Comment: Just fyi, `chrono` is expecting major improvements in C++20 in the area of calendars and time zones.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, Howard. I'm really looking forward to those improvements. C++/WinRT will specialize `clock_time_conversion` as soon as it's available to convert between the `time_point`s for `DateTime` and `utc_clock`/`system_clock`.

I've mentioned that I'm a huge fan and advocate of chrono, right? :)

Comment: If you ever need any `chrono`/date/time help, you know where to find me (I'm easily googlable). :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the documentation issue. If I understand correctly, there is no immediate way to get a `DateTime` (or `std::chrono::time_point`) in UTC as is, without going through a C API, by either converting to `FILETIME`, or using `<ctime>`. That's likely *the* reason I have never been as big a fan of std::chrono as you are. Although that is surely going to change by the time Howard Hinnant's extensions get merged into C++, finally making std::chrono universally useful.